# How to navigate to a different page using Id in Django

Tags: django, navigation, materialize

I'm Using materialize CSS scrollspy with Django to navigate to a specific section inside a page using section id. How can I navigate that specific section when I'm on a different page.

```
          

              <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#cat" >sample categories</a></li>
              <li><a href="/category">Categories</a></li>
              <li><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about">About Me</a></li>
              <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
```

````
 <section id="cat">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="center">Few Categories I do</h3>
                    {% for category in categories|slice:":3" %}
                        <div class="col s12 m4"> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

add to your html code `<section id="cat"><a name="cat"/>`

and then you can use links like `<a href="{% url "YOUR_CATEGORY_URL" %}#cat">to category</a>`

Comment: It fixes the problem but partially. But I can not see the smooth scroll effect on page

Comment: this is not the django way to do it. You should never hard code your url in a template. Please see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62698065/11576212

Comment: you absolutely right, but the question was about how to make url to certain part of html page. so in my example YOUR_PAGE_URL hsoul replace with {% url "..." %}, will change it in my answer to avoid any mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it in the url if i understood the question right.
if your on /home, in href put: /category/#cat

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<h3 class="center">Few Categories I do</h3>
   {% for category in categories|slice:":3" %}
      <a href="{% url 'home' %}#{{ category }}">Click me!</a>
```

`home` is the name or your target url.